# not able to run video file in emulator

Tags: android

> Blockquote

can anyone suggest me how to give the path for playing a video, which video file is placed in locally and  how to give the path for the video file which is stored in a website.here is the code below i tried but it is not working  .

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

Alas, I could not see your code, but this is usually done using the `setDataSource()`-method of class [`MediaPlayer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html):

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

MediaPlyer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
if (PLAY_FROM_FILE) {
  File mediaFile = new File("SOME_MEDIA_FILE");
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mediaFile);
  mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
}
else {
  //playing from the Web:
  mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://exmaple.com/someVideo.mp4"); //works also for rtsp
}
mediaPlayer.start();
```